# How the dataconsitency maintained in callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know how the callbacks are maintaining the data consistency when there is a case of creating/updating child records.

For example I have an model called Server which has many IPs, so whenever I delete the server I want to change the status of IP as "Free". Currently I am doing it in before_destroy callback in Server model, so whenever the server is getting deleted the IP status will be changed to "FREE".

But I want to know what will happen if the before callback is executed and server deletion is aborted due to some exceptions/db level errors? I cannot change the status of the IP after deleting the since I have foreign key constraint in db level, so the DB wont allow me to delete server before removing the IP table link.